# AttributeError: 'RPCReply' object has no attribute 'data_ele'

Tags: python, cisco, yang

I'm getting this error**" AttributeError: 'RPCReply' object has no attribute 'data_ele'"** when I try to run the below python script

Please help me to solve this problem

```
import lxml.etree as et
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from ncclient import manager
from ncclient.operations import RPCError

payload = [
'''
<get-config xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
  <source>
    <running/>
  </source>
  <filter>
    <interfaces xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces">
      <interface>
        <name>GigabitEthernet1</name>
        <description/>
      </interface>
    </interfaces>
  </filter>
</get-config>
''',
]

# connect to netconf agent
with manager.connect(host="sandbox-iosxe-recomm-1.cisco.com",
                         port="830",
                         username="developer",
                         password="C1sco12345",
                         timeout=90,
                         hostkey_verify=False,
                         device_params={'name': 'csr'}) as m:

        # execute netconf operation
        for rpc in payload:
            try:
                response = m.dispatch(et.fromstring(rpc))
                data = response.data_ele
            except RPCError as e:
                data = e._raw

            # beautify output
            print(et.tostring(data, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution yet, still working.
But, try our this code below, if you are trying to write to a note_file.. It might help.

```
                response = m.managers[id].dispatch(rpc['rpc_template'])                    

                print("\n\n****************   Printing Response   ********************** ")
                print(response)
                print("\n**************** Response Printed ********************* ")

                directory = "results/"+vendor+"/"+tec+"/"+m.managers[id].host+"/"+rpc["operation"]
                file = open(directory + '/' + testcase[0] + '_rpc-reply.xml', 'w+')
                file = open(directory + '/' + testcase[0] + '_rpc-response.xml', 'w+')

                print("\n\n****************  Writing Response in Results file  ********************** ")
                file.write(etree.tostring(response,pretty_print=True))
                file.close()
                print("\n**************** Response Written to the file ********************* ")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).